# IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value of type java.lang.String for parameter markup with expected type of java.math.BigDecimal

Tags: jpa, jpql, illegalargumentexception

When I execute the below query,

```
public int checkIfQueryExist(String query){
    List<Product> products= em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.markup=:markup" ).
            setParameter("markup", query).getResultList(); 
    return products.size();
}
```

I get the below exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value of type class java.lang.String for parameter markup with expected type of class java.math.BigDecimal from query string SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.markup=:markup.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.setParameterInternal(QueryImpl.java:937)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.setParameter(EJBQueryImpl.java:593)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.setParameter(EJBQueryImpl.java:1)
    at enterpriseBeans.Operations.checkIfQueryExist(Operations.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 60 more
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I've added the full stack trace :) Would really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is hidden right there in the stack trace

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value of type class java.lang.String for parameter markup with expected type of class java.math.BigDecimal from query string SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.markup=:markup.`

Just try to convert `query` to type `BigDecimal` in your `checkIfQueryExist` method

Comment: What would be your suggestion to address this? I'm just so new to this. Thank you :)

Comment: You are executing the query with the wrong type for the `markup` parameter. It is a `String` but it is actually of type `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Where/how do I change it to BigDecimal?

Comment: Currently, I'm guessing that the `markup` property in your `Product` Class is `BigDecimal`. So when you query on `Product` you have to use the correct type. In your `checkIfQueryExist` method change  `setParameter("markup", query)` to `setParameter("markup", BigDecimal.valueOf(query))`

Comment: It is giving me an error on netbeans when I do that, that it is not a suitable method found for valueOf(string), method BigDecimal.ValueOf(long) is not applicable

Comment: Yup, my bad :) `setParameter("markup", new BigDecimal(query))` should do the trick.